# Segmentation fault when running C program (putchar() and multidimensional array pointers)

Tags: c, putchar

I'm trying to run the following code on C:

```
#include "ex1_1.h"

void path(char **adj_mat, int u, int v)
{
        printf("test\n");
        char temp = *adj_mat[1];
        putchar(temp);
}

int main()
{
    int u = 5;
    int v = 5;
    char mat[5][5]={
    {'0', '1', '1', '1', '0'},
    {'0', '0', '0', '0', '1'},
    {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
    {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0'}
    };
    char** adj_mat = (char**)&mat;
    printf("Mtest\n");
    path(adj_mat, u, v);
    return 1;
}
```

and I'm getting "Segmentation fault".

I don't know why, I'm guessing that it's related to how I'm using putchar() with multidimensional array pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: `char** adj_mat = (char**)&mat;` is of no use. `mat` is already a char **.

Comment: No. it's not. arrays are not pointers.

Comment: But they behave like so. Yeah, I should have prepended a `const`.

Comment: @H2CO3: Pointers to pointers do not behave like pointers to arrays!

Comment: @H2CO3 only in very specific conditions.

Comment: @Anthales right. Sorry, just overlooked it. Yes, there are 2 levels of indirection here.

Answer (score 3):

A `char[5][5]` **is not** a `char **`.

Declare your `path` function as one of these (they are equivalent):

```
void path(char (*adj_mat)[5], int u, int v)
void path(char adj_mat[5][5], int u, int v)
```

and use it like

```
path(mat, u, v);
```

---

Update: Now to the reason for the segfault.

`mat` is a 5-array of 5-arrays of `char`, which will "decay" into a pointer to 5-arrays of `char` when used as an expression. This means that `mat` can be used as if it is a pointer to a 5-array. In general a n-array of type `T` will decay into a pointer of type `T` (note that `T` does **not** decay!).

So note you use `mat` as an expression when you pass it to your function `pass()`. In C it is not possible to pass an array as-is to a function, but it can only "receive" pointers.

So what's the difference between a pointer to pointer of `char` and a pointer to a 5-array of `char`? Their type. And their sizes.

Suppose you have a pointer to a pointer to a `char` - let's call it `p` and we have a pointer to a 5-array `q`. In short: `char **p` and `char (*q)[5]`.

When you write `p[i]`, this will be equivalent to `*(p+i)`. Here you have pointer arithmetic. `p+i` has the value (which is an adress) `p` plus `i*sizeof(char *)` because `p` points to a `char *`.

When you look at `q`, `q+i` would have the value `q` plus `i*sizeof(char[5])`.

These will almost always be different!

---

**Update** (real answer now): It's even worse in your case as you are "forcing" `char (*q)[5]` "to be" a `char p**` (via your invalid typecast), so in your call

```
char temp = *adj_mat[1];
```

`adj_mat[1]` will look at the 2nd row of your matrix an try to interpret its value as a pointer (but it is a 5-array!), so when you then dereference via `*adj_mat[1]` you will land somewhere in nirvana - segfault!

Comment: Now i'm getting: **ex1_1.c: In function ‘main’:
ex1_1.c:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘path’ from incompatible pointer type**

Comment: How did you declare `path` and how are you calling it? If you did like I told, you should have no problems.

Comment: @user128877: So.. did you get it running?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion `(char**)&mat` is undefined behavior. `&mat` is `char(*)[5][5]` (In words, pointer to array of 5 arrays of 5 chars), and you can't convert it to pointer to pointer to char.

I would write `path` like (assuming C99):

```
void path(char *arr,int u,int v) {
 char (*adj_mat)[v]=arr;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: &mat is char[5][5], since the addressof of an array returns the array reference itself (since you can't pass an array by value, only by reference). AFAIK, &mat should be the same as mat.

Comment: @H2CO3 as far as I know, you are wrong. the value of `&mat` is the same as of `mat`, but the types are different. `&mat` is pointer to array, and you can dereference it like any pointer. (consider `mat[0]` against `&mat[0]` - they have the same relation)

Comment: you're right in the question of types, but their value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
char temp = *adj_mat[1];
```

to

```
char temp = adj_mat[1];
```

The problem is that in

```
*adj_mat[1];
```

you try to dereference a pointer to an invalid address, namely the ASCII code of '1' (I suppose).

Comment: Nope. adj_mat is an ARRAY OF ARRAYS. adj_mat[1] is still a char *, not a char.